# Load nib from file path

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

We might have a need for loading a nib using the results of

```
[NSBundle -pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization:]
```

I thought this would be possible, but all the methods I can find only want the name not leading path info.

We are exploring a way to provide both fr-Fr and fr-CA through one code base.  Our client wants a fr-CA translation and we're afraid we might have another customer that wants a fr-Fr translation. I was thinking we could path to correct nib based on the selected language.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path lookup takes into account the user's locale preferences. If you provide the proper localization directories (`.lproj`), the right nib should be loaded by the system.

Per [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The method first looks for a matching resource file in the non-localized resource directory of the specified bundle. (In Mac OS X, this directory is typically called Resources but in iOS, it is the main bundle directory.) If a matching resource file is not found, it then looks in the top level of any available language-specific “.lproj” directories. (The search order for the language-specific directories corresponds to the user’s preferences.) It does not recurse through other subdirectories at any of these locations. For more details see Internationalization Programming Topics.

Unfortunately, Apple's documentation is self-contradictory and incomplete. If you look at "Internationalization and Programming Topics", section "Language and Locale Designations", you will find under "Language and Locale IDs" this gem:

> **Important:** In iOS, the bundle interfaces do not take dialect or script information into account when looking for localized resources; only the language designator code is considered. Therefore if your project includes language-specific project directories with both a language and region designator, those directories are ignored. The bundle interfaces in Mac OS X do support region designators in language-specific project directories.

This is not entirely true. If you look at Apple's own applications, you will see that iOS does support some region designations, but only the ones Apple cares about. See for example the list of .lproj directories in a recent Mobile Safari:

```
$ ls -d *.lproj
Dutch.lproj/    el.lproj/       pt_PT.lproj/
English.lproj/  en_GB.lproj/    ro.lproj/
French.lproj/   fi.lproj/       ru.lproj/
German.lproj/   he.lproj/       sk.lproj/
Italian.lproj/  hr.lproj/       sv.lproj/
Japanese.lproj/ hu.lproj/       th.lproj/
Spanish.lproj/  id.lproj/       tr.lproj/
ar.lproj/       ko.lproj/       uk.lproj/
ca.lproj/       no.lproj/       vi.lproj/
cs.lproj/       pl.lproj/       zh_CN.lproj/
da.lproj/       pt.lproj/       zh_TW.lproj/
```

Notice that two Chinese regions, a British English region, and a Portugal Portuguese region are supported. But none of these solves the problem of `fr_CA` versus `fr_FR`.

For that, let's look at MobileSafari again. It must implement its own smart lookup, because it has plenty of more finely distinguished `StaticBookmarks-xx_YY.plist` files.

So, that's the solution: Use the locale functions that are still available, and do your own lookup accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response but the apple docs state the ios will ignore language directories that contain a region designator.  This is what i'm seeing if I add a language directory fr-CA and set my phone to French I don't get the French nib.

Comment: Please provide a link to the relevant documentation, or quote sufficient unique verbatim text that I can search for the documentation myself.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the detailed response.

Comment: Hey Jeremy one more question. How could we look up the nib? Can I load a nib from a specific directory?

Comment: If you package your nibs for a language in a bundle nested within your app's bundle, you can supply the bundle along with the nib name, and let the framework run the lookup. Your job would then be to figure out which bundle to use as the base location of all your nibs. Another possibility is to load your nibs using `+[UINib nibWithData:bundle:]`. As for performing lookup, if `NSBundle` gets in your way, you can always get your main bundle's `bundleURL` and use `NSFileManager`'s methods to examine the files packaged with your app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the problem.
You can perfectly have two different NIBs, for France and Canada (french), as it's supported by Xcode.

Simply add new localization for your file(s):

[image]

Then use a view controller to load the NIB, with the `initWithNibName` method. The correct one will be used, depending on the device language settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the ios will look languages directories that have a region.  From the appl docs    Important: In iOS, the bundle interfaces do not take dialect or script information into account when looking for localized resources; only the language designator code is considered. Therefore if your project includes language-specific project directories with both a language and region designator, those directories are ignored. The bundle interfaces in Mac OS X do support region designators in language-specific project directories.

Comment: The above comment should read the ios will NOT look at language directories that have a region designator.